# What kind of set_major_locator should I use?

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I have a question regarding a `plot` feature when the X-Axis is a date.

**Setting**

I have a two time-series `dt` and `x`, where `dt` is a list of `datetime.datetime` values and `x` is a `numpy` array object.

```
dt = 
[datetime.datetime(1996, 12, 3, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(1996, 12, 4, 0, 0), 
 ...,
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 5, 0, 0), 
 datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 8, 0, 0)]

x = 
array([29.06262, 29.26933, ..., 208.41999, 208.44532])
```

and both have the same length.

When I plot them as :

```
ax.plot(dt, x, color='black', lw=2)
```

I get a chart which has X-Tick Labels as their years (e.g. `1994, 1998, 2002, 2006, 2010, 2014`).

After some zooming, the X-Tick Labels nicely start showing months (e.g. `Aug 2009, Oct 2009, Dec 2009, Feb 2010, Apr 2010, Jun 2010`).

After further zooming, the X-Tick Labels again nicely start showing days (e.g. `Jan 14 2010, Jan 21 2010, Jan 28 2010, Feb 04 2010, Feb 11 2010, Feb 18 2010`).

**Question**

Now, I am trying to draw a custom chart (e.g. say using `LineCollection`) instead of using the default `plot`.

I suspect I would need to use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(???)` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(???)` to get the same feature of the X-Axis as in the default `plot` function.

What do I need to provide (i.e. `???`) to `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(???)` and `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(???)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you assumption was right: You have to set the locator and formatter manually. The "regular" ones are available in `matplotlib.ticker` and the ones related to dates in `matplotlib.dates`. There is quite a variety of fixed ones (e.g. WeekdayLocator, MicrosecondLocator, etc.), but also the automatic ones that you get when using `plot`.

So this should do it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# all your fancy plotting code

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter())

plt.show()
```

Further reading: http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html

#### Extra:

Be careful with you list of datetimes: matplotlib has an internal date/time representation (number of days as floats) and thus datetime objects need to be converted before plotting. In `plot` this conversion happens automatically, for custom graphs you might have to do that yourself with [`matplotlib.dates.date2num`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num).

Comment: The tree diagram on the matplotlib site made me say out-loud: "seriously?"